# What is the name of the "Activity" object?

Tags: standard-objects, activity, developername

I have been trying to find the API name of Activity object, but I am unable to find it. I require it because I want to delete 500 subtype custom fields records in the activity object.

Does anyone know the actual name of this object?

Answer (score 2):

Activities are tracked using Tasks and Events. By definition:

> Activities include events and tasks. With Salesforce, track meetings and tasks together in lists and reports to easily prioritize your time and keep up with your accounts, campaigns, contacts, leads, and opportunities.

You will need to look at Task/Event object for details on it.

More details on activity on [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual Activities sObject - it’s either Task or Event.

Check out the ERD here
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm