# Create lookup relationship from custom object to Event (Activities) object

Tags: event

Sorry for my English. It is my second language. I'm currently looking for new job and I'm completely new to Salesforce, and this company is willing to hire me if I do test activity in Trailhead on my own, but I can't seem to figure out how to do 1 particular bit:

> 11. Create a custom object ‘Participants’ with a lookup relationship to the Contact Object + (this part I managed to do)
>
> - and to the Activities (Event) object.
> - Add the Participants related list to the Event page layout.

I'm googling and googling for a few hours now, but no luck. I would really appriciate any help.

Comment: There is not much need to Google. If you cannot find the Event or Task on lookup list, it is likely not supported. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82098/is-it-possible-to-create-a-lookup-or-a-master-detail-field-to-event-from-my-cust

Comment: Alirhgt, but they are having some workaround in mind I think, otherwise they wouldn't put it there for beginner?

Comment: When you create a custom object, there is an option to check "Allow Activities". It will provide you an option to have WhatId (label: Related To) associated to the custom object.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom object, there is an option to check "Allow Activities". It will provide you an option to have WhatId (label: Related To) associated to the custom object.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but no idea how to proceed to connect it to Event object still. Can you please show me the right direction?

Comment: Populate the WhatId of Activity with the related custom object record. You should have a Activities related list on page layout. You shall see the list of activities in the related list.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do that? I only managed to find "Related to" field in Event object. I can't find any fields for Activity object.

Comment: The "Related To (WhatId)" field is a polymorphic field can accept many types of record ids other than Contact/Lead. Please read this post and documentation mentioned here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215196/activity-object-api